# Xfce Ubuntu internal crash - no programs are opened, such as terminal

Tags: 18.04, xorg, xfce, crash

When I open a program in my DE (even terminal, or appfinder except thunar), nothing shows up; then after some time, it shows me a crash report. Then I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd> to switch from x server DE to a command line interface, I can now open programs like vim in the terminal, but not graphics needed programs like vscode. What should I do? (Restart didn't help, even restarting lightdm.service didn't)

Comment: Post the crash report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed. Removed vala-panel-appmenu, and it's ok now, but I'm wondered why? It has been a while I'm using appmenu as my global menu on xfce panel, but I rebuilt it because of some problems and this crash happened. Gonna open an issue on gitlab, for those who have my problem.

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd>
- `$ sudo apt-get purge vala-panel-appmenu vala-panel-appmenu-common vala-panel-appmenu-registrar`